# Just One Button Is Disaligned in GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to generate a grid-style list of buttons. It works, except for one of the buttons, which is the only one without a `drawable` inside it. I'm not sure how to make it be lined up with the other buttons.

Here are the class methods:

```java
// test values
private static final int CURRENT_LEVEL = 8;
private static final int LEVEL_CAP = 20;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_select);

    generateList();
}

public void generateList() {
    GridLayout layout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    layout.setColumnCount(5);

    for (int i = 1; i <= LEVEL_CAP; i++) { // for every level there is

        Button btn = new Button(this);

        // 200x200 size
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        btn.setTextSize(14);

        if (i < CURRENT_LEVEL) { // already completed the level
            setTopDrawable(btn, R.drawable.ic_checkmark_holo_light, i);

        } else if (i == CURRENT_LEVEL) { // current level being completed
            //setTopDrawable(btn, 0, i); // gets the same result as the line below
            btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));

        } else if (i > CURRENT_LEVEL) { // these are the locked levels
            setTopDrawable(btn, R.drawable.ic_lock_lock, i);
        }

        layout.addView(btn);
    }
}

public Button setTopDrawable(Button btn, int id, int i) {
    // put the drawable with its id = id on top
    btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, id, 0, 0);
    btn.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    btn.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
    btn.setText(String.valueOf(i)); // put the level text under the drawable

    return btn;
}
```

Here is the relevant layout:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mikeyaworski.whoisthatyoutuber.LevelSelect" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

**How can I get button 8 to be lined up with the others?**

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use blank (transparent) icons the same size as your checkmark and padlock, and call setTopDrawable for that blank icon. If you don't want to do that, then you'll just have to work with margins and padding on the current item to get it to line up.

Comment: @Bruce The problem is that then the text would be on the bottom of the button for no reason. I want it to be centered and I want to make it larger as well. I'd prefer to work with margins and padding, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: For most of the items you are calling setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20). Experiment with making that call with different parameters for your CURRENT_LEVEL case, e.g. setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0). You might need to call getLayoutParams, cast it to MarginLayoutParams, and modify the margins.

Comment: @Bruce If I call `setPadding(0, 95, 0, 0)` on the disaligned button, it lines it up in the same way it would if I just had a blank image. So the text is on the bottom. `95` is the top padding, so it's pushing the text *down*, but for some reason is also pushing the entire button *up* in the layout. I don't understand why and I don't know how to center the text after doing that.